# Erro de sintaxe ao ler arquivo CSV

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Estou tentando, a partir de uma tabela csv, retirar determinadas informações que não me são úteis, mas no código há um erro, segundo o python 3, mas que eu não consigo perceber o erro.

> O erro está na linha 08, (arquivo = open('salicapiprojetos02.csv',
>   encoding = 'utf8')), com a seguinte mensagem: SyntaxError: invalid
>   syntax

Segue o código

```
import csv
import pandas as pd


arquivo_wri = open('projeto_dira.csv', mode='w', encoding = 'utf8')
arquivo_projeto = csv.writer(arquivo_wri, lineterminator = '\n')
arquivo_projeto.writerow(['nome', 'valor_captado', 'segmento', 'area']        

**arquivo = open('salicapiprojetos02.csv', encoding = 'utf8')**
for registro in csv.DictReader(arquivo):
                         int(registro)
                         if registro['valor_captado'] != 0:
                             nome = registro['nome']
                             valor_captado = registro['valor_captado']
                             segmento = registro['segmento']
                             area = registro['area']
                             arquivo_projeto.writerow([nome, valor_captado, segmento, area])

arquivo_wri.close()
```

Comment: Não faltou fechar os parênteses do `writerow` da linha anterior?

Comment: Sim, Lucas! Um lapso meu! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Olá!!

O problema esta nesta linha na verdade:

```
arquivo_projeto.writerow(['nome', 'valor_captado', 'segmento', 'area']
```

esta faltando fechar o ")".

Comment: Verdade, Karen. Como sou "verde", nem percebi. Muito obrigado! De verdade! ^^